# getting no such element when tryin to click <li onclick=> python

Tags: python, html, selenium

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(., "+origin_iata_code+")]").click()
```

thats the code im trying to use

while origin_iata_code is the elements in the list:

```
 ['FLL', 'MCO', 'AFL', 'ATM', 'AJU', 'ARU', 'AAX', 'NVT', 'BRA', 'JTC',...]
```

and in the html there is

```
 <li onclick="selecionou('FLL', this,'.txtBusca1', 'true', 'origem', 'Estouem1', 'FLL');">Ft. Lauderdale - Miami (FLL)</li>
```

(there's one for each, i've checked..

Comment: Are you looping through the list, such that origin_iata_code is a single element each time?

Comment: i used self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@onclick[contains(.,"+origin_iata_code+")]]").click() and it worked.. thanks!

Comment: now i've got a different problem.. its a nag><